# How does rabbitmq sync messages?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, message-queue, pika, python-pika

I use this simple code using `pika`:

```
conn = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = conn.channel()

def on_message(ch, method, properties, message):
     print("Received message: %r" % message)
     channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

channel.queue_declare(queue='my_queue', durable=True)
channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1) 
channel.basic_consume(on_message, queue='my_queue')
channel.start_consuming()
```

**Question:**
Once I got a message, and my `on_message` callback is running, how can rabbitmq make sure not to give the same message to other worker, until I call `basic_ack` ?  Since in my tests, if I won't call `basic_ack` the message will be sent again if I run the code multiple times.  Does rabbitmq has some timeout from the moment it send the message, until it gets an `ack`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can rabbitmq make sure not to give the same message to other
> worker, until I call basic_ack ?

Delivering a message to only one consumer is a ***core feature*** of RabbitMQ. The message will remain un-acked until the consumer to which it was delivered acks it, or the channel on which it was delivered closes.

> in my tests, if I won't call basic_ack the message will be sent again
> if I run the code multiple times.

When you run your code multiple times, here is what happens:

- RabbitMQ delivers the message to your consumer, moving it to the un-acked state.
- You stop your consumer application without calling `basic_ack`, which closes the channel and connection without acknowledging the message.
- RabbitMQ detects this and re-enqueues the message.
- You re-start your consumer, and it is re-delivered the message.
- Lather, rinse, repeat.

All of this and much, much more is covered in the [RabbitMQ documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/documentation.html).